# My toString() method isn't working and I can't figure out why, does anybody know whats happening

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that can tell whether or not a person needs to get a flu test based on their temperature and number of symptoms, but for some reason my toString() method refuses to work. I just need somebody to tell me why the toString() method refuses to work. The output of this code should be:

```
"Alice should be tested for the flu due to her 102 F temperature and aching muscles and fatigue."
```

when all I get as an output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 21, end 27, length 26 
        at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
        at FluDiagnoser.<init>(FluDiagnoser.java:20)
        at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        FluDiagnoser tester = new FluDiagnoser("Alice", 23, 102, "aching muscles and fatigue");

        System.out.println(tester);

  }
}
```

FluDiagnoser.java:

```
public class FluDiagnoser {
  private int age;
  private String name;
  private double temp;
  private String symptoms;
  int x = 0;
  int symptCount = 0;
  int andFix = 5;
  
  public FluDiagnoser(String name, int age, double temp, String symptoms) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.temp = temp;
    this.symptoms = symptoms;

    int symptL = symptoms.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < symptL; i++) {
      String commaStr = symptoms.substring(i, i + 2);
      String andStr = symptoms.substring(i, i + andFix);
      String cAndStr = symptoms.substring(i, i + 6);
      if (commaStr.equals(", ") && !cAndStr.equals(", and ")) {
        symptCount += 1;
      } else if (andStr.equals(" and ")) {
        symptCount += 2;
      } else if (cAndStr.equals(", and ")) {
        andFix = 2;
        symptCount += 2;
      } else {
        symptCount = symptCount;
      }
    }
    if (symptCount >= 2) {
      x++;
    } else {
      x = x;
    }
    if (temp > 100.4) {
      x++;
    } else {
      x = x;
    }
  }

  public void changeSymptoms(String change) {
    symptoms = change;
  }

  public String getSymptoms() {
    return symptoms;
  }

  public String toString() {
    if (x >= 2) {
      return name + " should be tested for the flu due to their " + temp + " F tempurature and " + symptoms + ".";
    } else {
      return name + " doesn't need to be tested for the flu.";
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand what's happening to make this program not work

Comment: In the stack trace `at FluDiagnoser.<init>(FluDiagnoser.java:20)` means that the problem is in the constructor (at line 20, to be precise), not in the `toString` method. So what is line 20?

Comment: what is `x = x;` supposed to do?

Comment: well you are looping from 0 to the length of the String.  When i is at the end of the String (i == symptL - 1) then what do you think happens with `symptoms.substring(i, i + 2);` ?

Comment: @federico line 20 is `String cAndStr = symptoms.substring(i, i + 6);`

Comment: If i is larger the `symptoms.length()-6` then the `substring()` method can not extract a substring of length 6 from `symptoms` and therefore fails with the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. This is what the message of the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` tries to tell you: "begin 21, end 27, length 26" - the end of the substring that you are trying to extract is beyond the end of the actual string and this is not allowed.

Comment: @ThomasKläger is there a way for me to fix that without removing my system for tracking the amount of symptoms the person has?